# Intercept android network traffic (firebase calls)

Tags: android, adb, http-toolkit

I need to intercep firebase requests from an android app.

I tried HTTP Toolkit, but it doesn't track firebase requests.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PCACDroid](https://github.com/emanuele-f/PCAPdroid). It offers an Android VPNService to be able to intercept any network traffic. As proxy to record TLS encrypted traffic you can use [MitmProxy](https://mitmproxy.org).

Starting with Android 7 user defined CAs for MITM solution are not working anymore easily. Take a look at [tls decryption](https://emanuele-f.github.io/PCAPdroid/tls_decryption) or how to tweak your application to use a [NetworkSecurityConfig](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config)

You could also just use an older device if you have one. This simplifies the process a lot.

Comment: I tried to unpack the application, and then rebuild, but got no luck. The rebuilded APK couldn`t be installed, I made some research on that, but no solution. I will try the other solution on the link you sent, and update here later.

Comment: When repacking the solution sometimes some special aapt switches has to be passed and the app must be also resigned. But rooting the phone and use VirtualXposed might be simpler.

Answer (score 0):

com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: An internal error has occurred. [ java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException:Trust anchor for certification path not found. ]

This is how I solved the error I mentioned above.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
  <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
    <domain includeSubdomains="true">example.com</domain>
  </domain-config>
</network-security-config>


<application
        android:name=".example"
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
</application>
```